# python testing as an independent script

Tags: python

I have taken a below code from a large code repository of interdependent modules. I want to run this as an independent unit for testing.

In below while calling db_obj.create_connection() i have to pass the value of debug_obj which means I have to import all the dependent implementation of that which I do not want.

However, if I pass None as db_obj.create_connection(None) then it will fail at debug_obj.info('inside create_connection')  due to attribute error. Unless I go and disable debug_obj.info() wherever used.

What could be the best possible way to handle such a situation where you wanted to disable you dependent library codes just for your unit testing without commenting its callings.

```
import pyodbc

class DBOperations(object):
    def __init__(self,db_params):
        self.db_params=db_params
        
    def create_connection(self, debug_obj):
        debug_obj.info('inside create_connection')
        mycode_to_run_create_connection

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    db_obj = DBOperations(db_params ='param_for_db_connection')
    db_obj.create_connection(None)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like using the [`mock` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) would be a good way of dealing with a situation like yours.

In your case, a [`Mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock) or [`MagicMock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.MagicMock) should do the trick.

In the same place where you are instantiating the `DBOperations` class, you could mock the `debug_obj`:

```python
from unittest.mock import Mock
...
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    debug_obj = Mock()
    db_obj = DBOperations(db_params ='param_for_db_connection')
    db_obj.create_connection(debug_obj)
```

Once the `Mock` object has been instantiated, attributes can be assigned to it, for example:

```python
debug_obj = Mock()
debug.info = print

debug.info('test')
# >>> prints the word test to the stdout
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.        While mocking the object 'debug_obj'  can we change its behavior to something else like print() ?      so that when  we can call  debug_obj('print msg')  it gets converted as    print('print msg')

Comment: You're welcome - Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Yes it worked but additional help as below                                                                                                                                                                        While mocking the object 'debug_obj' can we change its behavior to something else like print() ? so that when we can call debug_obj('print msg') it gets converted as print('print msg')

Comment: It should be possible. Try `debug_obj = Mock()` and then `debug_obj.info = print` before passing in into `create_connection()`.

Comment: Wow it is working like a charm.....thank you so much.

Comment: Brilliant, I've extended the answer, you appreciate if you could accept it.